# Auto display info windows on markers from directionsRenderer

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The directionsRenderer creates a marker at the origin and end destination. Right now i have to click a marker to display the info window. How do i automatically display the info window? The process of creating the 2 markers is abstracted into the directionsRenderer so i'm not sure how to find the 2 markers.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use the `suppressMarkers` parameter of the `directionsRenderer`

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true
});
```

2) Add your own markers on the start (and/or end) point(s)

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/J8aCH/)</kbd>

3) Call the `open()` method of the `infoWindow` to force it open
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?#InfoWindow

Hope this helps.